# Method of cryptography that doesn't need encryption key for decryption

Tags: encryption

Is there a method of cryptography that doesn't need the encryption key for decryption?

I thought public-key cryptography would work, but both the private and public keys are needed for decryption.

---

With public-key cryptography the private key can be used to compute the public key. While E cannot be computed, it is only 8 bytes and in implementations I've seen is hard coded to 65537.

So to ask the question in another way, is there an algorithm where the encryption key can only encrypt and the decryption key can only decrypt and neither key can be used to compute the other key?

Comment: Why? What problem are you trying to solve? This sounds like an ["XY problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: To encrypt, sender uses public key of receiver. To decrypt, the receiver uses private key.

Comment: @Ben I'm trying to figure out if I'm wrong about public-key cryptography or if every article that says you decrypt with just the private key is.

Comment: @Ben "both the private and public keys are needed for decryption" -- where did you get this idea?

Comment: Wait, do you mean that you want to have separate, secret and totally unrelated keys? Basically, 2 private keys; one for encryption and one for decryption?

Comment: @schroeder Is there an implementation of a public-key algorithm that doesn't require any part of the public key?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: @schroeder That's what people often assume they're getting when articles state that the private key is used for decryption. They assume that if they keep both keys private then the first "private" key can encrypt and the second "private" key can decrypt. I know they assume this because I've had to explain otherwise and recently I ran into code that uses this assumption. So I'm asking if what people assume exists or is even possible.

Comment: We can't answer what people assume. We can only explain how things work.

Answer (score 2):

[Kerckhoff's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle) states that for an encryption algorithm, the algorithm is assumed to be public, and the security of the algorithm relies completely on the key.  Thus, in order to have security in your encryption algorithm, some key is going to be required for decryption.  (This is encryption meaning *encipherment*; other cryptographic algorithms, such as hash algorithms, which do not encipher text can be secure without a key.)

In the case of public-key algorithms, you don't need both the public and the private key to decrypt; only the private key is needed.  It is often, however, the case that the private key contains certain parameters or values that are also part of the public key, either because they are necessary or because including them makes operations more convenient or efficient.

For example, with RSA encryption, the public key contains N, the modulus, and E, the public exponent.  The private key usually contains at least N and D, the private exponent.  However, it also traditionally contains the two primes, P and Q, and other parameters to permit more efficient operation.  In such a case, N is not strictly necessary, since it can be trivially computed from P and Q, but we nevertheless include it for efficiency reasons.  In no event is E, which is entirely in the public key, needed for decryption, and so the public key itself is not typically required.

It *is* typically the case that if you derive symmetric encryption keys with a Diffie-Hellman key exchange that you need *your* private key and the *other party's* public key, but that's because you're doing a key exchange.  The same party's public and private keys are not required.

Comment: So you're saying the public key isn't needed, but that's only because the public key can be computed from the private key?

Comment: @blackbox: You cannot compute the public key E from the private key D. You can only do this if you also have P and Q, which are contrary to D are not needed for decryption. See [Given a private RSA key, how do we get the public key?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8701/given-a-private-rsa-key-how-do-we-get-the-public-key).

Answer (score 0):

The goal of encryption is that the recipient must be able to extract the message, but an attacker should not - even if the attacker has access to the encrypted message. This is achieved by having some kind of secret, which is known to the recipient but not known to the attacker.

"Not known to the attacker" means of course that the secret cannot be an extractable part of the encrypted message. But it also means a high entropy for the possible secrets, so that the attacker is not able to somehow guess the secret in acceptable time.

Such secret can be the decryption algorithm itself or it can be the parameter for the decryption algorithm, i.e. the decryption key. High entropy is much easier to achieve by having randomized parameters (the key) for an algorithm than to have a huge variety of algorithms to choose from. Therefore it is typically assumed that the algorithm used is not a secret, but instead the decryption key is.

This means that there is no sane encryption method without an high-entropy decryption key.

This does not mean though that the decryption key is the same as the encryption key. The idea of public key cryptography is that encryption is done with the public key, while decryption is done with the matching private key. Public and private keys are related to each other, but they are different. It is not possible to derive the private key (which is the secret decryption key) from the public key. And the public key (encryption key) is not needed for decryption, only the private key (decryption key) is.

Comment: Can you please tell me which public-key algorithm doesn't need the public key for decryption?

Comment: @blackbox: for example RSA - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Decryption